# min-content with justify-self: right?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible with CSS3 grid to create such a layout?
All of the elements should be as wide as their content. And the last two elements should be right-aligned.

[image: layout specification]

However, the way I've tried does not work. As soon as a column has `min-content`, the `justify-self` property doesn't do anything.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "first second third";
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content min-content;
}

.first {
  grid-area: first;
}

.second {
  grid-area: second;
  justify-self: right; /* doesn't work */
}

.third {
  grid-area: third; /* doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first">first</div>
  <div class="second">second</div>
  <div class="third">third</div>
</div>
```

This is only a downsized version of a much more complex layout, therefore:

- I'm not looking for workarounds like creating wrappers
- Stretching `.first` is not an option because there will be calculations on that element
- The reason I chose `grid` over `flex` is because of the gaps

Comment: The problem to the solution is more easily achievable using flexbox. Some modern browsers support `gap` property for flexbox, which is similar to the `grid-gap` (https://caniuse.com/?search=gap). But, since it only has 70% of global usage what you can do is, you can utilise the padding to the flex items by setting their `box-sizing` to `border-box`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `gap` for `flex`. However, I don't think this problem is solvable with `flex` - at least not without creating additional wrappers. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Using flex will allow you to set `margin-right: auto` or `margin-left: auto` on either the left most or inner right most elements to push the elements around.

Comment: @LyndenNoye it will only push `.third` to the right (container end). If applied to `.second`, it will push it to the center.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flexbox may be more appropriate? note the margin-right on the first element in container 1, and margin-left on the second element in container 2. auto margins are quite powerful in flex containers.

```css
.container-1,
.container-2 {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
}

.item {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
}

.container-1 .item-1 {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container-2 .item-2 {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="item item-1">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item item-3">
    item 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-2">
  <div class="item item-1">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item item-3">
    item 3
  </div>
</div>
```